# Determining if a device is using HTC SenseUI

Tags: android

How can I tell if a device is using HTC's SenseUI?

I thought about using android.os.Build information, but they seem inconsistent.. is there a more definitive way?

I need to be able to tell if I can launch the calendar by using com.android.calendar or com.htc.calendar.

I welcome any suggestions!!

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but I would think twice before writing an app that depends on undocumented APIs like this.  Your app is bound to break as new phones come out.  See Commonsware's article regarding this: http://www.androidguys.com/2009/12/14/code-pollution-reaching-past-the-sdk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to use `PackageManager` to see if `com.htc.calendar` exists on the device. And  you can use `PackageManager` to derive an `Intent` useful for opening that package. Whether that will "launch the (HTC) calendar" is up to HTC and Android, not you.

Also, as Marya suggests, what you are doing is not a good idea, because there is no rule that HTC will use `com.htc.calendar` on every Sense device, now and in the future.

Comment: What's the better way to launch a calendar intent then?

Comment: @atolar: The Calendar application is not part of the Android SDK. There is no documented and supported way to "launch a calendar intent", for HTC or "plain" Android.

Answer (score 0):

Based on CommonsWare's suggestion, the following is what I ended up using. I hope this is helpful to others.

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
    Intent defineIntent = null;

    String thePackage = "com.android.calendar";
    String theClassName = "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity";

    try {
        PackageManager thePackageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        thePackageManager.getPackageInfo(thePackage,PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
        // regular android calendar doesn't exist

        // so try the htc sense one
        thePackage = "com.htc.calendar";
        theClassName = "com.htc.calendar.LaunchActivity";               
    }

    defineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        .setComponent(new ComponentName(thePackage, theClassName));

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
        0 /* no requestCode */, defineIntent, 0 /* no flags */);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String thePackage = "com.android.calendar";
String theClassName = "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity";
Intent defineIntent = null;

try {
    PackageManager PACKAGE_NAME = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    PACKAGE_NAME.getPackageInfo(thePackage,PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
    // regular android calendar doesn't exist
    // so try the htc sense one
    thePackage = "com.sonyericsson.calendar";
    theClassName = "com.sonyericsson.calendar.MonthActivity";               
}

defineIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
defineIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(thePackage, theClassName)); 
startActivity(defineIntent);
```